# How to change bounding rect values of contour in OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I want to change the value of the width of the next contour. I tried to do it this way but it turns out that it still retains the original values of contours. How do I do this? Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: This is the actual code I am working on.

```
temp = 0; #Holds the last element we iterated replaced value
for i,c in enumerate(contours2):
    [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(contours2[i])

    if i in percentiles: #if the current index is in the percentiles array
        [i, j, k, l] = cv2.boundingRect(contours2[temp]) #Get contour values of element to overwrite
        k = (x+w)-i 
        temp=i+1;   
#DRAW
for c in contours2: #when I draw it the k value of the overwritten elements doesn't change,why?
    [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit with what you want to do? Your code currently doesn't make sense to me. Each loop the values will be rewritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a misconception here, purely with Python that has nothing to do with OpenCV. Check the following code:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = a
>>> a = 7
>>> a
7
>>> b
5
```

When I set `b = a`, I'm setting `b` to have the same *current value* as `a`, but I'm not actually creating a new *name* for `a`. That means that later if I change the value of `a`, it doesn't affect the value of `b`. This is relevant because in your code, you're writing:

```
[i, j, k, l] = cv2.boundingRect(contours2[temp])
k = (x+w)-i
```

as if this modifies the contour. It doesn't; it just modifies the variable `k`. And you're simply overwriting `k` at each iteration of the loop.

Further, the bounding box is not the same thing as the contour. The contour hasn't been changed at all, because you're not modifying the `contours2` variable. You need to know whether you actually want the bounding box or the contour. The contour is a list of points which outline the contour shape. The bounding box is just that, the minimum size vertical/horizontal box that fits over your contour points. If you want to take the bounding box and modify it, then you should *store* the bounding box into a variable; in particular, if you're storing multiple bounding boxes, you'll want to store them into a list. For example:

```
bounding_boxes = []
for c in contours2:
    [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    bounding_boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
```

This will give you a list where the `i`th element is the bounding box around the `i`th contour. If you wanted to modify the bounding box that is stored, simply do it before you append it to the list:

```
bounding_boxes = []
for c in contours2:
    [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    w = w*2
    bounding_boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
```

What your code should be doing isn't completely clear to me, so I can't give you a fixed version, but hopefully this will get you headed in the right direction.